# DOMDocument xpath query cut off withing a specific timeframe ?

Tags: dom, xpath, domparser, xpathquery

is there a way to cut of the query and return back the results.. preset time to take to get all images from the given url .. i.e. query half of the webpage ? or job time not greater than 5 seconds, so therefore, it will get everything it can in 5 seconds.....

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $htmlget);
       $nodelist = $xpath->query( "//img/@src" );
```

Comment: Good question, +1. Yes, very roughly you could substitute the evaluation of one single XPath expression with separate evaluation of the items of a *sequence* of individual XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can evaluate *separately* any of the following XPath expressions one by one, and stop this process whenever a timer expires or other criterion is satisfied:

```
(//img/@src)[1]
(//img/@src)[2]
(//img/@src)[3]
...............
(//img/@src)[$N]
```

This can probably be speeded-up by chunking:

```
(//img/@src)[position() < 100]
(//img/@src)[position() >= 100 and position() < 200]
...............
(//img/@src)[position() >= 100*$N and position() < 200*$N]
```

Comment: wherre shall i put this position?   if i want to get only the first image it finds, what shall i do?   $xpath->query( "(//img/@src)[1]" );  ?

Comment: @dean_jase: Yes, seems like this -- I don't know your particular XPath engine API and have confidence that you know how to evaluate XPath expressions with it.